# How to get total quantity of products we have in each warehouse?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables

```
#Products  [Pro_ID] ,[Pro_Name],   
#Stock  [Stock_ID] ,[Pro_ID],[Warehouse_ID] ,[Qty] ,[Status]
Warehouse  [Warehouse_ID] ,[Name]
```

I am making a report for my asp.net project, that shows the total Quantity of products we have in each warehouse. I tried this query which shows nothing except of `Pro_ID` written as header with no data (0 row(s) affected).

```
SELECT Pro_ID from Stock
where Qty > 0
GROUP BY Pro_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Warehouse)
```

This is what i have recently in stock
[image: Stock table]

Comment: what about inner join of Stock and Warehouse? Then you need only select count(*), group By Pro_ID

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Warehouse)` is filter all of your results - you're asking for the IDs that have the same number of rows as the entire table.

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo..you can post it as a answer instead of a comment

Comment: It would help if you show an example of what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want to get what is in each warehouse:

```
SELECT w.Name, sum(s.Qty)
FROM Stock s 
INNER JOIN Warehouse w 
ON s.Warehouse_ID = w.Warehouse_ID
GROUP BY w.Warehouse_ID,w.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    Warehouse.[Warehouse_ID],
    Warehouse.[Name]
    #Products.[Pro_ID],
    #Products.[Pro_Name],
    #Stock.[Stock_ID],
    #Stock.[Qty],
    #Stock.[Status]
FROM
    #Stock
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Warehouse ON #Stock.[Warehouse_ID] = Warehouse.[Warehouse_ID]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #Products ON #Stock.[Pro_ID] = #Products.[Pro_ID]
```

Note that by starting with `#Stock` and outer joining to the two master tables, you only get results for which you have actual records in the `#Stock` table.  If you wanted all products at all warehouses, you would select `FROM Warehouse CROSS JOIN #Products` to get every combo of product and warehouse, then outer join that to your `#Stock` table to get records where they exist, and use null substitution to plug zeroes where you had no record in your `#Stock` table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from Stock s
INNER JOIN Warehouse w ON s.warehouse_id = w.warehouse.id
where s.Qty > 0
GROUP BY Pro_ID
```

Comment: So, you need to change GROUP BY condition. try group by warehouse_id

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear.  Are you looking for a product count by each product in each warehouse?  If so, this query should work for you:

```
SELECT 
  warehouse_id, pro_id, SUM(qty) AS quantity
FROM #stock
WHERE Qty > 0
GROUP BY 
  warehouse_id, pro_id
```

Comment: This only gives me the same result as i posted the stock table image

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what output you would like to see?

Comment: Like Warehouse 1--ABC = 100 Products
Warehouse 2--XYZ = 234 Products
I mean total no of products each warehouse has ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is still unclear.  Please use the column names you provided above to show what you want the output to look like in a result set.  Do you mean total number of products meaning how many different product ID's there are in each warehouse, or do you mean you want the quantity of each product?